# Warning en logo en Bridge al instalar una demo

Tags: php, wordpress

Una vez instalado el tema Bridge procedo a instalar una de las demos que vienen con él (modern en concreto). Al terminar la instalación veo que me sale un warning diciendo esto:

```
Warning: getimagesize(C:/xampp/htdocs/bridge11/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/bridgelogo_dark.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PruebaWordPressBridge\wp-content\themes\bridge\includes\shortcodes\shortcode-elements\slider.php on line 356
```

Es raro porque yo tengo instalado wordpress en otra ruta distinta a:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/bridge11/...
```

En otro directorio distinto a bridge11. Es decir, yo no tengo este directorio "bridge11". ¿Por qué entonces ha cogido esta ruta? ¿Dónde lo puedo cambiar? Al buscar el "slider.php" en la línea 356 veo esto:

```
list($logo_width, $logo_height, $logo_type, $logo_attr) = getimagesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$logo_url_obj['path']);
```

con lo cual no puedo cambiar la ruta aquí ya que es una variable constante (si no me equivoco :P) ¿Cómo podría arreglar este warning?

PD: además de este warning descrito hay un montón más pero creo que se deben a la misma causa, es decir, la ruta errónea descrita al principio.

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo wp-content\themes\bridge\includes\shortcodes\shortcode-elements\slider.php en la linea 356 hay que sustituir esto:

```
$logo_url_obj = parse_url($qode_options_proya['logo_image']);
list($logo_width, $logo_height, $logo_type, $logo_attr) = getimagesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$logo_url_obj['path']);
```

por esto:

```
list($logo_width, $logo_height, $logo_type, $logo_attr) = getimagesize($qode_options_proya['logo_image']);
```

Para el resto de "warnings" de tipo

```
[vc_row row_type=»row» type=»grid» text_align=»left» padding_top=»109″ padding_bottom=»76″ background_color=»#f8f8f8″][vc_column width=»1/1″][vc_row_inner][vc_column_inner width=»1/4″]
```

son debidos a que no se instaló el Visual Composer que viene con el demo que se está instalando. Una vez instalado y activado junto con sus plugins los "warnings" desaparecen.